# Node.js - I can't access config variables in app.js

Tags: node.js, config

As the name says, I am a hobbyist developer. I am learning node.js, which I really like. Unfortunately, I've hit a problem. In app.js I can't get to the environment variables.

My set-up is:

Windows 10 PC

VS Code 1.68

In package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
// and...
"dependencies": { 
"dotenv": "^16.0.1", 
"express": "^4.18.1", 
"morgan": "^1.10.0", 
"mysql2": "^2.3.3", 
"sequelize": "^6.21.2" 
}
```

When I type process.env. <-- a drop-down in VS Code appears here but my variable NODE_ENV is not in the list.

[Screenshot added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdhMP.jpg)

In config.env I have:

```
NODE_ENV=development

PORT=8000

UZERNAME=john

PASSWORD=123456x
```

In server.js I have:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = require('./app');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

console.log(process.env); // <-- The list displayed here includes my variables from config.env...
```

... I can see see my variables in the console, e.g.

```
UZERNAME: 'john',  <--- this is my variable.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can access them but intellisense won't autocomplete them in the editor. What you're looking for is [env with intellisense](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/using-env-variables-and-autocomplete-with-node-js-and-typescript-46b5b4a769d8)

Comment: @Nick ahhh... you are right!  I was expecting them to appear in an intellisense way!  And yep, I can access them.  I will be sure to read the article you link.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hope helpful for you
**Method 1**

```
process.env.UZERNAME
```

**Method 2**

```
process.env["UZERNAME"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load config before importing app.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const app = require('./app');

console.log(process.env);
```

Comment: I am a new user and I think I need more reputation before I can do that.